# How get the right information from these tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a list of all the employee names and their managers and I cannot figure out how to do it. I have attached the relational model. 
In DEPT we know the department number (dept_nbr) which is attached to EMPLOYEE through emp_dept and we know the department manager (dept_mgr) which is attached to EMPLOYEE through emp_nbr

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    mgr.emp_nbr ManagerID,
    emp.emp_nbr EmployeeID,
    emp.emp_lname, emp.emp_fname, 
    mgr.emp_lname as mgr_lname, mgr.emp_fname as mgr_fname
from 
    dept 
    inner join employee as mgr on dept.dept_mgr = mgr.emp_nbr
    inner join employee as emp on dept.dept_nbr = emp.emp_dept
```